# Unwise to install KDE Applications in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, kde

I have been doing a bit of reading.  It seems most people believe it is unwise to install KDE applications in Xubuntu, but nobody really explains why it is unwise.  Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has most likely historical reasons.

When you install Xubuntu with the expectation of a lightweight and small-footprint desktop environment, you might find the extra 50 MB of QT/KDE dependencies to be a too hefty pill to swallow just to run a few KDE applications. Given temporary storage sizes, the net effect is negligible unless you run a really old, embedded or resource constrained system.

Another point is that in the past KDE applications would not have the same look and feel as Gnome/GTK+ applications - this is mostly untrue these days - KDE/QT emulation of GTK+2 (xfce/lxde) is even better than GTK+3 (gnome-shell/unity).

Also a noteworthy mention is that KDE3 mostly relied on a homegrown DCOP-Server for program inter-operation. With KDE4, this has been replaced with D-Bus, which has become a de-facto standard. Additionally, the current audio back-ends and libraries like phonon, gstreamer and pulseaudio interact pretty well.

Summarily, there is none to little *technical* reason left to shun KDE-applications from a Xubuntu install, but outdated habits tend to perpetuate themselves first into superstitions, then into religiously leaded debates.